# How to add a custom icon to a google map v3

Tags: google-maps, icons

I have inherited some code below and all works fine. My question is how do I add a custom icon to this map? I have added one before but I don't know where I should put the code?

```
// initialize map
    var unitedKingdom = new google.maps.LatLng(55.378051, -3.435973);
    var options = {
        center: unitedKingdom,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 6
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // fetch and iterate over the winners
    var current = 0;
    $.getJSON('JSON_FILE.txt', function (winners) {
        var popup = setInterval(function () {
            (function (winner) {
                var newCenter;
                var location = winner.name.split(', '); // winner.location seems a bit unreliable (sometimes null)
                geocoder.geocode({ address: location[1], country: 'UK' }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        newCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
                        map.panTo(newCenter);
                        var contentStr = '<div class="infowindow">' + 
                                         '<p><strong>' + winner.name + '</strong> just won ' +
                                         '<strong>' + winner.displayAmount + '</strong> on ' + 
                                         '<strong>' + winner.game + '!</strong></p>' + 
                                         '</div>';
                        infowindow.setPosition(newCenter);
                        infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
                        infowindow.open(map);
                    }
                });
            })(winners[current]);
            // increment the current index, or reset it if we're on the last item
            current = (current < (winners.length-1)) ? (current+1) : 0;
        }, 3000)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation on custom icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#ComplexIcons), it includes an example.

As to where to put the code, it needs to be in the call back function for the geocoder, "newCenter" is the position you probably want the marker at.

In your code:

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: location[1], country: 'UK' }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    newCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
                    map.panTo(newCenter);
                    var contentStr = '<div class="infowindow">' + 
                                     '<p><strong>' + winner.name + '</strong> just won ' +
                                     '<strong>' + winner.displayAmount + '</strong> on ' + 
                                     '<strong>' + winner.game + '!</strong></p>' + 
                                     '</div>';
                    infowindow.setPosition(newCenter);
                    infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                }
            });
```

Add the custom marker like this:

```
geocoder.geocode({ address: location[1], country: 'UK' }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    newCenter = results[0].geometry.location;
                    map.panTo(newCenter);
                    var marker = new google.maps.marker({
                       map: map,
                       position: newCenter,
                       icon: customIcon,
                       shadow: customIconShadow,
                       shape: customIconShape
                    });

                    var contentStr = '<div class="infowindow">' + 
                                     '<p><strong>' + winner.name + '</strong> just won ' +
                                     '<strong>' + winner.displayAmount + '</strong> on ' + 
                                     '<strong>' + winner.game + '!</strong></p>' + 
                                     '</div>';
                    infowindow.setPosition(newCenter);
                    infowindow.setContent(contentStr);
                    infowindow.open(map);
                }
            });
```

Define customIcon, customIconShadow and customIconShape as required for your custom icon.

Comment: Thanks geo, having a hard time still. Could you show me where I insert this?

Comment: Added sample code to add the custom marker at "newCenter",  you need to define the custom marker, your original post implies you know how to define one. Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_markers_infowindows.html) that puts custom markers on the map.

Comment: Thanks a mil for the code but unfortunetly the marker, not the speech bubbble appear any longer. (The link to the icon is correct and the map is moving around, but just no speech bubble or icon)

Comment: What javascript errors are you getting? Can you provide a link to your map that exhibits the problem or a jsfiddle that does?

Comment: once I fixed the javascript errors and made the map variable global, it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dnsyU/2/

Comment: dude!! That is 99% it! Just one thing and again, I truly appreciate your time on this. Is there anyway to make the markers hidden again when it moves to the next one etc?

Comment: Yes.  marker.setMap(null) should hide the marker, you just need to make the marker global so you have access to it the next time the function runs, see: http://jsfiddle.net/dnsyU/3/